# django upload image using gridfs

Tags: python, django, mongodb, gridfs, djongo

I want to add two field for image upload in my model, I run `python manage.py makemigrations xxx_app`

[image: code]

But then I get an error `no module named 'gridfsuploads'`

[image: eror]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the question but a few notes. Could you share the code itself and not just images? Second, do you have all modules installed?

Comment: from the little info I could gather from your incomplete post, check that you added `gridfsuploads` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: Thank you all, it's resolved, I've removed the `gridfsuploads` settings.py file and use `djongo-storage GridFSStorage` , Thank you